# Add/Remove input fields with React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to add and remove input fields using 
react. I've managed to add the filed successfuly but cannot remove the field, or even trigger an alert! Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

```
let count = 0;
class RedirectURI extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        attributeForm: []
    };
    this.addAttributeForm();
 }
removeAttribbuteForm(){
    alert('boom!');
}
addAttributeForm() {

     count=count+1;
     console.log(count);

    var array = this.state.attributeForm;
    if (count >= 10){
       document.getElementById('addURI').style.display = "none";
       return false;

     } else {
     array.push(
          <div>
              <label htmlFor="redirect-URI">Redirect URI</label>
              <input name="redirect-URI" />
              <button className="remove-input" onClick= . 
            {this.removeAttributeForm.bind(this)}>remove</button>
          </div>
    );

    this.setState({
        attributeForm: array
    });
     }
}

render() {
  return (
      <div>
          { 
            this.state.attributeForm.map(input => {
                return input
            })
          }
          <button id="addURI" onClick= . 
  {this.addAttributeForm.bind(this)}>Add Redirect URI</button>
      </div>
  );
 }
 }

ReactDOM.render(<RedirectURI />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**ERROR**

```
react-dom.production.min.js:157 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
at RedirectURI.addAttributeForm (pen.js:30)
at new RedirectURI
```

Comment: What error you are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works with minor corrections. See [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-pare-dfl4f)

1. You have dots in `onClick=`
2. It seems you misspelled `removeAttributeForm`. Copy/paste original function name (which is `removeAttribbuteForm` with two `bb`) solves all errors